# Drupal Error: Undefined Offset: 0 error & Fastcgi

Tags: php, drupal, fastcgi, plesk

Thanks for reading this. I apologize if there is a simple solution to this but I have been through the forums/Google to find a fix and no luck as yet.

I am getting a Notice: Undefined offset: 0 error. The landing page renders but but all links shoot straight to a "Not Found" error page.

Are these two issues related? I read somewhere, that the Notice: Undefined offset: 0 error is from not having fastcgi as the php rendering engine. Is this correct? and will this solve that issue?

The server is Windows based with Plesk.

You can view the issue here
http://southbaypontoons.com.au/

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: We won't be able to help you with `Notice: Undefined offset: 0 error` if you don't show us the code.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue, where you are getting 404 files errors for all of your links looks like it might be a rewrite issue.

I am not sure what webserver you are using with Plesk for Windows, but most likely it is IIS - the webserver that comes with Windows.

See this page for the rewriterules: http://drupal.org/node/3854

This will work if you have the IIS rewrite plugin for IIS (http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) If it is not your own server, you may need to ask your webhost to enable it.

As for the missing images - they are there. Look for example at http://southbaypontoons.com.au/sites/default/files/banner/slider-img1.jpg ... this is the image that is on the top of the home page.

It seems like you need to go through all of your drupal content and remove the /drupal/ at the front of all the images.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! Turned out that it was due to the PHP rendering engine. After fastcgi was enabled it seemed to not show the errors. However, now it is painfully slow (but I believe that it is due to the poor quality server). I knew the images wouldn't load correctly. In the development environment I had to place the site in a sub directory due to limitations of the qnap server i was using. Thanks again though, it is really nice to get fast responses with clear information!